# Easy unit conversion in Kerr metric

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, unit-conversion, kerr-metric

I would like to use Kerr metric in [Boyer-Lindquist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Lindquist_coordinates) coordinates in geometrized units with mass of the black hole normalized to $M=1$. I am embarrassed to admit, but I can't seem to figure out how to relate this to the coordinate system or realistic astrophysical settings.

**My intuition:**

Geometrized: $c=G=1$

**4-velocity** is not affected by $M$

**mass** needs to be expressed in terms of $xM$, where $x$ is dimensionless

**length** is a unit of mass and needs to be expressed in terms of $x M$

**4-momentum** is a unit of mass and needs to be expressed in terms of $xM$

**Example:**

Sagittarius A* is roughly $M\approx 4\times 10^6M_\odot$

hence setting $M=1$ e.g.

1. $v=0.5$, $m=4M_\odot$, $l=5pc=1\times 10^{14}M_\odot$

would transform to:

2. $v=0.5$, $m=\frac{4M_\odot}{4\times 10^6M_\odot}=10^{-6}$, $l=2.5\times 10^7$

Is this ok?

Comment: I don't think you can normalise $M$. Simply put, $M$ is different from $c$ or $G$ in that they are constants that never change. However, you can set $M$ equal to if you change the definition of the units used, say that you define $M Kilogram (Kg) = 1 Otto gram (Og)$. Doing so of course, would allow you to keep the maths proper, but with a simplified equation much like using normalised units $c=G=1$.

Comment: @Horus 
Thanks. That actually clarified things a little. The following excerpt from Wiki was confusing me: "The geometrized unit system is not a completely defined or unique system: latitude is left to also set other constants to unity. We may, for example, also set Coulomb's constant, ke, and the electric charge, e, to unity."

Anyway thanks, and sorry for the somewhat embarrassing question. If you like, you can add this as the answer.

Comment: Nah I'll leave it as a comment. Also its alright, I myself had trouble with the natural units. Though I have long passed that phase, I highly dislike using those units. I find that the equations loses some of its elegance and accuracy in the process. It does simplify equations though that much is true.